# Why AWS aurora Read replica's slave status shows empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I have an Aurora replica, I know the primary and secondary instances are sharing an underlying Cluster volume.

When I run `show slave status` on the read replica, it shows nothing.

1. Why does it behave like this?
2. What kind of replication is aurora using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Aurora does not use MySQL [Binary Log File Position Based Replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binlog-replication-configuration-overview.html) method for its replication, which is why the [`SHOW SLAVE STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-slave-status.html) command does not show any information.
2. Aurora uses its own proprietary replication technology. See [Replication with Amazon Aurora](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Replication.html) for the available documentation. To monitor Aurora replication status, you typically use the Amazon RDS Console to view dashboards of the relevant CloudWatch metrics. See [Monitoring an Amazon Aurora DB Cluster](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Monitoring.html) for more information.